# equalprg with lisp (clojure) and custom indent settings

Tags: indentation, filetype-clojure, filetype-lisp

How do I make `equalprg` match my custom indent settings? They are like:

```
let b:did_indent = 1
set expandtab       
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2

set autoindent
```

And they format the code to this (actually I have to add the 2 extra spaces myself):

```
(. fs (writeFile "test.txt" "some text" (fn [err]
  (. res(send (if err "error" "done")))
```

And when I use `=`, this is what I got:

```
(. fs (writeFile "test.txt" "some text" (fn [err]
                                         (. res(send (if err "error" "done")))
```

How do I keep the first form?

Also, would it be possible to add the leading spaces automatically then, because I suppose they would be scrapped?

Comment: This one holds a further requirement not edited into the duplicate.

Comment: Is it acceptable to put `(fn [err] ...)` on the next line? I generally prefer function/lambda expressions in lisps to be aligned, which is probably what clojure's `indentexpr` is trying to do

Answer (score 1):

`equalprg` specifies an external program, there is no way for the external program to know your specific indenting settings, except for parsing your various configuration files.

In general it is better to go with the `indentexpr` setting, which can use various VimScript to perform your indentation (as well as call an external program).